# Login button inactive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I changed my form from using `form_tag` to using form..then login button could no longer submit to users account... someone help me figure out what the problem is.

view/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Admin Login</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" type="password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

sessions controller below

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   #skip_before_filter :authorize
  def new
  end

  def create
   user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
   if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
end
```

Routes file code below

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'dashboard#index'

  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  post '/users' => 'users#create'



  resources :applicants do
    root :to => 'applicants#index'
  end
end
```

Comment: You have to use the `<%= form_tag( { :action => :save, }, { :method => :post }) %>` if you are using it in an erb file. Your rails controller will not understand plain html form tags.

Comment: @sandeep could please help me explain the point of { :action => :save, } cause im using it and im getting routing errors

Comment: You should edit the above code for your controller. In your case it looks like it is for login. `{ :action => :login, }`

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the 
`<%= form_tag( { :action => :save, }, { :method => :post }) %>` 
if you are using it in an erb file. Your rails controller will not understand plain html form tags.